# Is it possible to check the call parameters in the test?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking, pytest

is it possible to check in the test with what parameters the method is called and what result it returns, if we call the main method **run** which calls the method I'm interested in - **self.get_request()**.

file.py

```
class A:
 def run():
    some logic...
    request = self.get_request()
    some logic...
    return response
```

test.py

```
from file.py import A
def test():
   """
   Inside this test, I want to check the parameters and the value returned by the
   get_request method, but I don't want to check it separately
   I want to check it by calling the parent method - run
   """
   instance = A()
   response = instance.run()
   assertions logic for instance.get_request..
```

I know that it is possible to mock a method and then we have access to the number of calls, parameters, etc. If what I'm asking is possible in some way through mock, I just want to add that my mock would have to have the same logic as the method it mocks (be the same).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is probably the `wraps` argument that can be used in  [patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html?highlight=patch#unittest.mock.patch) - this allows you to mock a function, while it still retains the previous (or some other) functionality (note that the argument itself is described under [Mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html?highlight=patch#unittest.mock.Mock)). As with any mock, this does allow you to test the calls and call args, but does *not* allow you to check the return value of the function. This has to be tested via its side effects (in your case via the returned `response` which should depend on the return value of `get_request`).

Here is an illustration for your case:

```py
from unittest import mock

class A:
    def run(self):
        request = self.get_request(21)
        return request

    def get_request(self, foo):
        return foo * 2

def test_run():
    instance = A()
    with mock.patch.object(instance, "get_request", wraps=instance.get_request) as mocked:
        assert instance.run() == 42
        mocked.assert_called_once_with(21)
```

In this case the mock calls the real `get_request` method and returns its result, while recording the call and the call args.
I added some argument to `get_request` for demonstration, and returned the result of the call directly in `run` - in your case this will differ of course, but the idea should be the same.